# Understanding <string> String Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Using the string library, I'm trying to allow the user to input a number of lines of symbols which I will later flip. To me, the most obvious way to do this seemed to be with an array of strings, however, though I believe my input system is correct, my output is always a massive string of random symbols resulting in an eventual "Abort". Is what I'm trying to do impossible? If so, why, and if not, how would I go about fixing this error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/* Function Declarations */
string flipHouse();

int main() {
        string flipped = flipHouse();
        cout<<flipped;
        return 0;
}

string flipHouse() {
        int n;
        cout<<"Enter the number of lines: ";
        cin>>n;
        string house[n];
        cout<<"Enter the house image:"<<endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
                getline(cin,house,'\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
                cout<<house[i];

return house[n];
}
```

Comment: This compiles for you?

Comment: What do you mean by flip?

Comment: @DavidO Yes, it does.

Comment: @0x499602D2 For example, if the user inputs ///[, the output would be "]\\\".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> string house[n];
> ```

This array contains `n` strings. Valid indices are 0 ... n-1. The behaviour of accessing the array out of bounds is undefined.

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
>         cout<<house[i];
> ```

In the last few iterations, you access indices up to n. That index is one past the end of the array.

> ```
> return house[n];
> ```

Here you return the string in the index n. That's again one past the last index. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Another problem is that `n` is not a compile time constant value. As such, it may not be used as the size of an array in C++.

Comment: Thank you so much! Does this mean that I am unable to have a variable as the number of strings in an array?

Comment: @DylanDalal Not necessarily. You could use a const variable with compile time constant initialiser.

Comment: Thank you both! I'll be sure to research both of these suggestions.

Comment: `string house[n]` with `n` a variable is not actually valid C++.  Variable-length arrays are a non-standard extension supported by some compilers.   If you want a container with a set of `n` strings, use `vector<string> house(n)` or (more completely) `std::vector<std::string> house(n)`.